# Нет ответа от сервера

Tags: java, android

Если проверить из браузера http://eventer.ooofarvater.ru/index.php?r=api_v1/user/login то получаю ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но из андроида получаю failed to connect to eventer.ooofarvater.ru/85.192.185.172 (port 80) after 10000ms

Пробовал retrofit и Volley, на реальном устройстве и эмуляторе,обновил android studio, при этом с другими ресурсами есть связь, но если поменять ссылку на данную выше то ответа не будет.

Ретрофит

```
public class APIClient {

public static APIInterface getApi() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://eventer.ooofarvater.ru/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);

}
}




 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("index.php?r=api_v1/user/login")
 Call<LoginAnswer> doPostLogin( @Field("username") String username, 
 @Field("password") String text);




   apiInterface.doPostLogin(login.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<LoginAnswer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<LoginAnswer> call, @NonNull retrofit2.Response<LoginAnswer> response) {
     .......
        });
```

Volley

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://eventer.ooofarvater.ru/index.php?r=api_v1/user/login";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.getCache().clear();
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Некоторое время назад связь с данным сервисом у меня работала.

Answer (score 0):

После удаления антивируса касперского проблема исчезла